# PHP - Listed directory files as navigation. How to display index first and display as 1?

Tags: php, navigation, directory

I am building a page navigation based on php files in a directory.

At the moment I have 5 files in my directory: index.php, 2.php, 3.php, 4.php, 5.php

With my limited PHP skills I have managed to work the code to display the navigation as: [2] [3] [4] [5] [index]

However I have hit a road block that is a little beyond me at this time.

I would like to have [index] displayed as [1], and I would like [1] to be displayed first.

I would like to have it look like this: [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]

```
<?php
    $pathfiles = "../directory/";
    $files = glob("../directory/*.php");
    foreach( $files as $file ) {
        echo '[<a href="'.($pathfiles).''
        .basename($file).'">'
        .basename($file, ".php").'</a>] ';
    }
?>
```

Any help or leads would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you always have a index file there? Then you could hardcode the link and exclude it from the loop. `if (basename($file)!='index') `

Comment: @Brandon, store the result of globing to an array, use @tepkenvannkorn approach to substitute `index` with `1`, finally, sort it and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to push the index.php value to the top before iterating;

```
$key = array_search('index.php', $files);
unset($files[$key]);
natsort($files);
array_unshift($files, 'index.php');
```

Then, in your iteration, just look for the value index.php and change it to [1]

Comment: Use `natsort()` to put the remaining files in numerical order, too.

Comment: I've added this to the example, but still - the files should be listed in the correct order from the start.

Comment: `glob()` uses lexicographic sorting, not natural sorting. In lexicographic sorting, 11 is between 1 and 2.

Comment: Ahh, sorry - totally missed that part.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning natsort that worked great. I had to change nat_sort to natsort. I was able to get [index] to [1] by using str_replace. However with what was provided above, [1] on the navigation is now being displayed both first and last. This seems to be my last obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$pathfiles = "../directory/";
$files = glob("../directory/*.php");
$list = array();
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $nb = basename($file) == "index" ? "1" : basename($file);
        $list[$nb] = '[<a href="'.($pathfiles).''.basename($file).'">'.$nb.'</a>] ';
    }
    ksort($list);
    foreach ($list as $l)
    {
        echo $l;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work properly. It still displayed as index and it did not display first.

Comment: That is because it checks for "index" and not "index.php".